# Laravel Displaying Specific Project Detail of User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a many-to-many pivot table (project_user) and am successful in getting all the projects of the authenticated user.

**WriterController.php**

```
public function writerProjects()
{
    $projects = auth()->user()->projects;

    dd($projects);

    return view('writers.projects', compact('projects'));
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('users/{user}/projects', ['as' => 'showProjects', 
    'uses' => 'WriterController@writerProjects']);
```

My question is how can I get the specific project's details? Here's my approach so far (it doesn't work though).

```
public function showWriterProjects($id)
{
    $projects = auth()->user()->projects;

    foreach($projects as $p)
    {
        dd($p->name);
    }

    return view('writers.projects.show', compact('projects'));
}
```

**web.php for that**

```
Route::get('users/{user}/projects/{project}', ['as' => 'showSingleProject', 
'uses' => 'WriterController@showWriterProjects']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many-to-Many relations have been defined in User.php and Project.php, they seemed pretty obvious to post.

Comment: There's a bit too much wrong here to concisely answer; your routes are wrong (missing params in your functions), using `auth()` instead of `User::where(...)`, getting all projects and not using `$id` (which should probably be `$projectId`), etc. etc. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I have many-to-many relation between project and user, how do i use User::where(...) for my purpose.

Comment: Your route has `{user}` as a param, which would be like `1`, so you'd have to use `User::where("id", "=", $userId)` instead of `auth()->user()`. But, this is too broad; narrow your question down to a single problem, and read through more of the documentation.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have removed {user} param and probably will figure out what this is.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not clear what is meant by "project's details", I'll go with project name.

Just imagine you only need 'name' attribute of 'projects'

**Controller**

```
public function showWriterProjects($id)
{
    $project_names = auth()->user()->projects->map->name;

    return view('writers.projects.show', compact('project_names'));
}
```